# Why does dart has got special keywords for get and set?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I was just wondering special keywords for getter and setter. Why has dart kept special keywords `get` and `set` for getter and setter respectively? Is there any particular reason, because like other languages it could have been done with simple functions also.

Example in dart we have get and set keywords.

```
class Person {
  String _name;
  String get name => _name;
  set name (String val) => _name = val;
}
```

In java, we do the same using public methods.

```
// Java, No get, set keywords used
public class Person {
  private String name; // private = restricted access

  // Getter
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  // Setter
  public void setName(String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }
}
```

Why do we need separate get and set keywords in dart? Is that different from a normal getter and setter methods that we use in java, cop

We could simply use

```
class Person {
  String _name;

  String getName() => _name;
  void setName(String val) => _name=val; 
}
```

I know this is something like using variables directly instead of methods, Simply my question is Is there anything that we can't achieve in a simple getter and setter methods that we can do using `get` and `set` keywords?

Comment: can you clarify which other languages you mean, and provide an example? e.g. kotlin also has a get/set keyword.. i can't think of a language which allows overriding properties with "normal" methods.

Comment: @herbert java, cpp, python

Comment: you can't overload class member variables with methods in java.. and python also as a `@property` syntactic sugar for getattr/setattr

Comment: `get` and `set` are for custom getters and setters, in case you want to override the default implementation, or have properties without a backing field. You can then use those custom getters and setters with normal property syntax (e.g. `String get fullName { return "$firstName $lastName"; } ... print(foo.fullName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically for convenience and backward compatibility. Let's say you start off with a public field:

```dart
class Person {
  final String name;
}
```

but then you decide name should rather be a calculated field based on first and last name:

```dart
class Person {
  final String lastName;
  final String firstName;
  String get name => '$firstName $lastName';
}
```

in java it is a best practice to never, ever have a public class member variable, just because it doesn't have a way to transition to a method without changing the API. so you ALWAYS have to write `getVariable()` acessor methods, even if 99% of those only have `return variable;` as body.